# How can I get an audio notification when multiple long running command have finished?

Tags: shell, command-line, audio

This question is similar, but different of
[How can I get an audio notification when a shell command have finished?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/447466/how-can-i-get-an-audio-notification-when-a-shell-command-have-finished)
I am looking for a command that can be used like

```
sleep 2 &; sleep 1 &; sleep 5 &; sleep 3; bell
```

giving an audible notification after 5 seconds.

I use `zsh` in a `KDE` `konsole`.

Answer (score 0):

How about

```
sleep 2 &; sleep 1 &; sleep 5 &; sleep 3 &; for job in `jobs -p` ; do wait $job ; done ; bell
```

(simplified from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/356100/how-to-wait-in-bash-for-several-subprocesses-to-finish-and-return-exit-code-0)?

Side note: I tested in GNU bash, Version 4.3.48 instead of zsh and used beep instead of bell. My actual command was slightly different:

```
sleep 2 & sleep 1 & sleep 5 & sleep 3 & for job in `jobs -p` ; do wait $job ; done ; beep
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use `sleep 2 & sleep 1 & sleep 5 & wait; xkbbell -force`. You may need to run `modprobe pcspkr` as root.

Comment: which shell supports single `&` there between commmads?

Comment: @αғsнιη I am not sure there is any such shell, unless you're not joking.