# How can I get an audio notification when a shell command have finished?

Tags: shell, command-line, audio

This question is similar, but different of [How can I get an audio notification when a long running command has finished?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/447464/how-can-i-get-an-audio-notification-when-a-long-running-command-has-finished).

I am looking for a command that can be used like

```
mayberunlongtime; bell
```

I vaguely remember a command working and used like this exist, without remembering the name.

There is an ASCII character for ringing the bell, but using '\a' printf for this would look somewhat non-obvious, or even opaque. And it did not work when I tried.

I use `zsh` in a `KDE` `konsole`.

Comment: Some terminals support notification on no console activity (no output). Does this replace what you're looking for?

Comment: i found a previous posted question at this link: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/1974/how-do-i-make-my-pc-speaker-beep i hope it will be of some help.

Answer (score 0):

The command line program *mpg123* can be used to play an MP3 file from a script:

```
High Performance MPEG 1.0/2.0/2.5 Audio Player for Layers 1, 2 and 3
    version 1.22.4; written and copyright by Michael Hipp and others
    free software (LGPL) without any warranty but with best wishes

usage: mpg123 [option(s)] [file(s) | URL(s) | -]
supported options [defaults in brackets]:
   -v    increase verbosity level       -q    quiet (don't print title)
   -t    testmode (no output)           -s    write to stdout
   -w f  write output as WAV file
   -k n  skip first n frames [0]        -n n  decode only n frames [all]
   -c    check range violations         -y    DISABLE resync on errors
   -b n  output buffer: n Kbytes [0]    -f n  change scalefactor [32768]
   -r n  set/force samplerate [auto]
   -o m  select output module           -a d  set audio device
   -2    downsample 1:2 (22 kHz)        -4    downsample 1:4 (11 kHz)
   -d n  play every n'th frame only     -h n  play every frame n times
   -0    decode channel 0 (left) only   -1    decode channel 1 (right) only
   -m    mix both channels (mono)       -p p  use HTTP proxy p [$HTTP_PROXY]
   -@ f  read filenames/URLs from f     -T get realtime priority
   -z    shuffle play (with wildcards)  -Z    random play
   -u a  HTTP authentication string     -E f  Equalizer, data from file
   -C    enable control keys            --no-gapless  not skip junk/padding in mp3s
   -?    this help                      --version  print name + version
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `<command>; xkbbell -force`. You may need to run `modprobe pcspkr` as root.

Answer (score 0):

`<command>; echo '\a'` works for me.